# Is there any Windows Store class equivalent to the ImageFormat class?

Tags: c, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In an app I am developing I want to offer the option to convert an image to a selected format, such as JPG PNG TIFF and so on. In winforms i would simply use the ImageFormat class and just save the image with the selected ImageFormat. How would I go around doing this in the Windows Store App without this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.createasync.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [`BitmapDecoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder) and [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) class. It supports quite a few formats. I have some code [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions.cs) that picks the right encoder id for specific file extension.